# In Ireport if we pass map as a parameter from java to ireport how to access map values based on key of ireport field

Tags: java, jasper-reports

From java code I pass a parameter to ireport like this

```
fillReportToFile(sourceFilename, map, beanColDataSource1);
```

where map is something like this

> AFG, [1, 2] AZE, [1, 1] BAN, [0, 1]

where key is country_name and the list are values .
Now I need to access this in Ireport with key as country_name 
I tried following in ireport,

```
$P{$F{COUNTRY_NAME}}.get( 1 );
```

but it gives parse errors.

Can anyone suggest me some way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue

((List)($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($F{COUNTRY_NAME}))).get(1)